# Cakephp use groupby and get the highest id only

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, group-by

I'm using below query to get the unique result for receiver_id but also trying to get the highest id returned only rather than lowest one which is what below find query is generating. Is there a way we can change the find optional parameters to get highest id returned only?

```
$this->loadModel('Chat');
        $lastChat = $this->Chat->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Chat.user_id' => $user_id['User']['id']
            ),
            'order' => array('Chat.id DESC'),
            'fields' => array(
                'Chat.id',
                'Chat.chat',
                'Chat.user_id',
                'Chat.receiver_id',
                'Chat.read',    
                'Chat.created'
            ),
            'group' => array('Chat.receiver_id')
        ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it only makes sense to use a `GROUP BY` clause in SQL if you are going to use an aggregate function in the `SELECT` clause.

Maybe I'm not understanding the nature of your problem, but would this query work for you?

```
SELECT Chat.receiver_id, MAX(Chat.id)
FROM chats Chat
WHERE Chat.id = X
GROUP BY Chat.receiver_id
```

If that's the case you just need to add an extra element in the `fields` array:

```
$this->Chat->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => ...,
  'order' => ...,
  'fields' => array(..., 'MAX(Chat.id) as max_id',...),
  'group' => ...,
);
```

Comment: That solution works and is in line with this link: ["Example using GROUP BY"](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php) headline. However, in my experience, the other fields (not `id`) in the results array will not be from the same line for some reason, so pointless to include them.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to achieve what you're after.

```
$this->loadModel('Chat');
$lastChat = $this->Chat->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
        'Chat.user_id' => $user_id['User']['id']
        ),
        'order' => array('Chat.id DESC'),
        'fields' => array(
            'Chat.id',
            'Chat.chat',
            'Chat.user_id',
            'Chat.receiver_id',
            'Chat.read',    
            'Chat.created'
        ),
        'order' => array('Chat.receiver_id DESC'),
        'limit' => 1
    ));
```

There's no need to use `GROUP BY`. Just use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.